# How to make onmouseover work on the ipad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, touch

I'm a Javascript beginner and I'm trying to make this code I wrote to work on the iPad.
The idea is that when the user hover over a div it changes the picture.
I can not use canvas as I'm using animated gifs, and they don't work.
How can I monitor the user finger position on screen in order to make it work?

here is the code:

```
<style>
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

div.btn {
width: 20%;
height: 768px;
display: block;
z-index: 99;
float: left;
/* border:solid #444; */
top: 0;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseover(x)
{
if (x == 1){
var box = document.getElementById('box'); 
box.style.background='url("spin01.gif")';
}
if (x == 2){
var box = document.getElementById('box'); 
box.style.background='url("spin02.gif")';
}
if (x == 3){
var box = document.getElementById('box'); 
box.style.background='url("spin03.gif")';
}
if (x == 4){
var box = document.getElementById('box'); 
box.style.background='url("spin04.gif")';
}
if (x == 5){
var box = document.getElementById('box'); 
box.style.background='url("spin05.gif")';
}
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="box" style="background: url('spin03.gif'); width:1024px; height:768px; display:block; padding:0;">
<div class="btn" id="btn1" onmouseover="mouseover(1)"></div>
<div class="btn" id="btn2" onmouseover="mouseover(2)"></div>
<div class="btn" id="btn3" onmouseover="mouseover(3)"></div>
<div class="btn" id="btn4" onmouseover="mouseover(4)"></div>
<div class="btn" id="btn5" onmouseover="mouseover(5)"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I guess, that if I can track the postilion of the finger I could just drop the 5 btn divs and set the if statements according to the position.

Comment: you dont have that in ipad, what you can do is add jquery mobile fx and use `tap` for hover effect and `taphold` for click action

Comment: what is the difference effects that you have there... is not possible to do the same in css3 ?

Comment: I want the image to change according to where the user touches the screen. but I don't want him to Tap. I want the motion to be fluid without the need to tap again and again. as the above code works on the pc.

Comment: Then you cant , is touch screen , so they don't have hover

Comment: Again I don't need to use hover. I want to emulate the effect shown in the code above. And I know this can be done as there more then a handful of working examples of similar nature. like the "TouchSwipe" plugin. but all the ones I found are in Jquery and I don't know that yet.